# HTTP Response... GET, POST?

Tags: httprequest, httpresponse

I understand that HTTP Requests can be either GET, POST, etc. But what about the HTTP Responses? Are they also like the HTTP Request, in that they can also be GET, POST, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http resposes return a status code. 200 means ok. Take a look at the http spec.

Comment: Thank you for that... but what about in the case of sending back json data? Can that be sent back using GET or POST?

Comment: GET and POST normally contain a message body, so yes.

Comment: ??? I am really confused now. I had a look at the specs.. and I don't remember reading anywhere that the HTTP Response could be sent back using GET or POST. Can you please confirm this information.. or even better... point me to the source of this information. Thanks in advance.